# Error installing WiFi driver RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806 on linux kernel 4.19.50-2 make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop

Tags: wifi, make

I just got a WiFi dongle (Volans VL-UW120) that is ostensibly Linux compatible, with 802.11 ac standard. If I can't get it to work I can take it back and get a refund. I just ran the install script and got this output with error:

https://gist.github.com/jamesray1/b855bb63384bb138b1d6b042c5530d41

This is the last part with the make error:

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
Password: 
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.19.50-2-MANJARO/build M=/home/jr/RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806/driver/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806.20161025_BTCOEX20161024-3333  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.19.50-2-MANJARO/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.19.50-2-MANJARO/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1874: modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Here is a link to the Linux folder/driver that is in the CD that came with the dongle, along with the system's details, and again the output of the script: https://mega.nz/#F!x9EQyYCZ!Z1TX9HCH2mX5Q6goog3ebA.

The driver name is RTL88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.1.7_19806.

The kernel of my desktop is 4.19.50-2-MANJARO x86_64.

I've cross-posted this in https://forum.manjaro.org/t/ac-wifi-dongles-2019-h2/112452/2.

Comment: It looks like you're using the same device that I am. Try this version: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959. I've successfully built it on kernels 4.18 and newer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now!

Comment: I got an error when I got to the `dmks build` step:
https://gist.github.com/jamesray1/07e3bb5066e20a425d517f83ec961e56

Comment: Similar error here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kernel-headers-cannot-be-found/12907

Comment: Running `sudo pacman -S linux419-headers` now.

Comment: Ah what am I thinking I ran `sudo pacman -S linux419-headers` on my laptop, but that's not relevant as I need WiFi on my desktop, and can't run that command! USB tethering doesn't work. I'll have to try setting up an Ethernet connection between the laptop and desktop, as per https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-connect-a-desktop-to-the-internet-via-ethernet-to-a-laptop-with-the-laptop-connected-via-wifi-to-a-mobile-hotspot-with-both-on-manjaro-linux/112740/2.

Comment: Looks like you're on the right track.

Comment: Yeah I'm just posting my findings in case others have the same issue.

`sudo ethtool eno1 | grep MDI` output `MDI-X: off (auto)`

Comment: Ah I think this is too time-consuming, I think I'll try to get one that is plug and play. `➜  ~ cat /sys/class/net/eno1/address       
00:26:b9:e0:a5:6c
` Added this line `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="00:26:b9:e0:a5:6c", NAME="net0"` via `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/10-network.rules`. However when I ran `ip link set up dev net0` I got `Cannot find device "net0".` Following instructions from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Change_interface_name.

Comment: On further thought I'll just get a fixed landline optical fibre broadband connection (NBN in Australia) and connect the desktop to the router via Ethernet.